# Sending different data to an embedded component in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, drag-and-drop, components

I've got a drag and drop setup in two views, currently.  I am trying to pull those out and make reusable components out of them.  At this point I'm not even worried about the actions and bringing that information back (that will be the next issue that I will look into).  Right now I'm only worried about getting the proper data to display.

The templates for my current setup are:

The outside list view:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  {{#each view.permission}}
    {{ view App.GroupsPermissionView }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The individual item view:

```
<li class="sortable-item">{{ this.displayName }}</li>
```

I have changed this into the following component templates:

drag-and-drop.handlebars:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  {{#each dad}}
    {{ drag-and-drop-item dadi=this.displayName }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and drag-and-drop-item.handlebars:

```
<li class="sortable-item">{{ dadi }}</li>
```

I call this with `{{ drag-and-drop dad=unselectedPermissions }}` or `{{ drag-and-drop dad=selectedPermissions }}`

and this works fine.

Here is my issue.  My other use of drag and drop does not use the field name of "displayName".  The field is just "name".  I'm sure other co-workers will need to also use other field names as well.

I've tried many different things to attempt to get it passed through to the inner component, but nothing has worked.  I think it is a limitation in handlebars and that this will be impossible to do.

Any idea of what could be done here, if anything?

**Edit: An update**

I've got things somewhat closer...but now I've run into another related issue.  Here's my current drag-and-drop.handlebars:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  {{#each dad}}
    {{ drag-and-drop-item self=this dadi=../field }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here's drag-and-drop-item.handlebars:

```
<li class="sortable-item">{{ dragAndDrop self dadi }}</li>
```

And here's drag_and_drop_helpers.js:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("dragAndDrop", function(context,value) {
  return this.self.get(value);
});
```

I realize that context isn't being used above, I've got it in there because of testing I was doing.

Here's the thing...with the code above, I get the correct 'this'.  If I return "this.self.get('displayName');" in the helper, it works.  However, the ../field isn't being returned in the template.  I so wish you could have nested {{}}'s...then this would work!

To get the ../field working, I found I could make the following change to drag-and-drop.handlebars:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  {{#each dad}}
    {{#if ../field}}
      {{ drag-and-drop-item self=this dadi=../field }}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But if I do this, 'this' isn't the right one, so I'm getting 'displayName' through, but the wrong context.

It seems I can have one, or the other, but not both.

I could really use some help here.

Comment: I've updated the description of the problem.  Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out, after quite a few days of searching and trying lots of things.

I did not realize that you could use "view." to pull the information.

Here's the call to this:

```
{{ drag-and-drop dad=unselectedPermissions field="displayName" }}
```

Here's the working drag-and-drop.handlebars:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  {{#each dad}}
    {{ drag-and-drop-item self=this dadi=view.field }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here's the working drag-and-drop-item.handlebars:

```
<li class="sortable-item">{{ dragAndDrop dadi }}</li>
```

Here's the working drag_and_drop_helpers.js:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("dragAndDrop", function(value) {
  return this.self.get(value);
});
```

I'm hoping this helps someone in the future so they don't repeat mistakes I've made.

Now, on to figuring out the coding for the component.js...